# Redirecting to a URL from iframe gives Access-Control-Allow-Origin error - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect, iframe

I have a angular webapp that the client runs in an iframe

within the webapp I redirect to a url specified by the client in a properties file

```
$window.top.location.href = urlClientProvides;
```

when it tries to redirect I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://castst.cleintUrl.com:8080/cas/login?service=http%3-someURL-Findex.jsp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://lnx1.cleintUrl.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there a way within my app to redirect the client to "urlClientProvides" or would they need to make changes on their side to the page using the iframe ?